Establishing Quantitative Links Between Regulatory Activity Marker H3K27ac ChIP-seq and Differential Gene Expression, Without Hi-C or PLAC-seq Data
I am working on correlating H3K27ac ChIP-seq data, which indicates gene expression-related activity in regulatory regions, with RNA-seq gene expression data to establish quantitative connections between gene expression and regulatory activity marker H3K27ac. Specifically, I am comparing two distinct cell types, resulting in differential gene expression (DG = log2FC(G2/G1)) and differential H3K27ac (DH = log2FC(H2/H1)) based on ChIP-tag count differences. My approach involves the following steps:

Identify Active Differential Peaks: Select H3K27ac peaks with |DH| above a certain threshold.
Associate Peaks with Genes: For each active differential peak, identify the closest 2-3 genes based on genomic distance.
Intersect with Differentially Expressed Genes: Determine the overlap between these associated genes and those with |DG| above the threshold.

This method assumes that differentially active H3K27ac peaks primarily regulate nearby genes. However, I am not sure if this a good assumption, as active peaks might regulate genes in much farther proximity than nearest two or three genes. In the absence of any additional data such as Hi-C or PLAC-seq, which can explicitly link promoters and distal enhancers, are there alternative methods to narrow down a list of genes that maybe associated with specific active enhancer peak region? I would appreciate any critiques to this approach for connecting H3K27ac activity and gene expression.
